# context menu in a macOS Safari content blocking App extension

Tags: swift, macos, safari

How is this achieved?
the only way I see to do it, is by creating two seperate extensions?
One being the content blocker, and the other being a regular extension with the ability to add a context menu etc...

surely this can't be true...?

Answer (score 0):

The new way Apple has laid out for Safari App Extensions is for there to be a separation between the traditional extension--such as content scripts and toolbar menus--from content blockers.

These can all be put together in a single Mac OS application, but have to be separate sub-applications within that context.